# Tensorflowjs Save Model throws Error: Unsupported TypedArray subtype: Float32Array

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

I have a tensorflowjs (1.2.7) proof of concept running local on my mac.  All is working well, I can create a model and make predictions however when I try to save. I get the following error.

```
 Unsupported TypedArray subtype: Float32Array

      at node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/io/io_utils.ts:207:13
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at concatenateTypedArrays (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/io/io_utils.ts:199:6)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/io/io_utils.ts:93:17)
      at step (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/io_utils.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/io_utils.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/io_utils.js:20:58)
```

This only seems to happen when I save.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
model.save('file:///path/to/my-model');
```

I am using the node-specific version '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'.
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load#native_file_system_nodejs_only

I'm reluctant to take this approach ([TensorFlow.js: Saving different model instances during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555854/tensorflow-js-saving-different-model-instances-during-training)), it sounds like you lose 
aspects of the model this way.

Comment: Float32Array is [supported](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/master/src/io/io_utils.ts#L205). Could you show more of your code. Are you using any other wrapper libraries maybe and  how are you loading the numbers?

Comment: Thanks for planting this thought in my head.  I was running this code through Jest (as a unit test).  When I run via jest it fails every time.  When I refactored the test runner to use vanilla JS it worked just fine.

Comment: Glad I could help. I could also add it as more detailed answer for future visitors if you are okay with that.

Comment: is this something specific to Jest? Is it worth setting up to use another lib eg Ava for testing? I have exactly this issue and wondering how much time to sink into other options.

Answer (score 0):

This was related to running inside a Jest unit test.  This is not an issue otherwise.

Comment: erg I hit exactly this problem. So we can't use jest to test it eh... :(

Comment: well, got the same issue using Jest. So it's related to jest it seems.